# count occurrence based on 2 conditions

Tags: excel-formula

Hi I have a table below where I want to count the occurrence of the credit based on Name and class.

A name can have multiple class but it should count the unique credit occurrences.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=--(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,@A:A,C$2:C2,@C:C)=1)`
[image]